# VSTO ClickOnce ends with "The application could not be downloaded because a connection to the network could not be established."

Tags: outlook, vsto, clickonce, manifest

Using an Apache Ant task we generate and sign the manifests for a Microsoft ClickOnce VSTO deployment. For one specific ClickOnce install, we are getting the error:

```
The application could not be downloaded because a connection to the network could not be established.
Ensure that you can connect to the network, and try again.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

Answer (score 1):

The signtool.exe started from Apache Ant re-evaluates the contents of the directories. When you by accident include an executable (*.exe) in the directories, the error "The application could not be downloaded because a connection to the network could not be established." is raised by clickonce during installation of your product.

### Background

During the signing and with an executable present, the header of the manifest in the folder with the DLL-s changes from

```
<entryPoint>
  <co.v1:customHostSpecified />
</entryPoint>
```

to:

```
<entryPoint>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Invantive.Estate.App" version="20141.0.14188.24543" language="neutral" processorArchitecture="msil" />
  <commandLine file="Invantive.Estate.App.exe" parameters="" />
</entryPoint>
```

That there is an error is correct because the manifest is not what I intended, but the message text is a little confusing.

Comment: Great observation that unknown executables in the click-once deployment installer directory will cause this error.  Thanks!

Comment: @JoelMC happy to hear it helped. Enjoy :-)

Comment: @GuidoLeenders I'm having the same issue and I don't really know how to fix it...can you please tell me which is the file that I need to modify?

Comment: @Valip it is in the manifest. Small file in the deployment folder.

Comment: After I modify this file should I be able to copy the `[AddIn].vsto` file and run it on another machine?

Comment: @Valip I don't understand the question. Please raise the question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders I raised a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732766/excel-add-in-not-working-after-publish. Thank you!