# Excel Add-In not working after publish

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto, add-in

I've created an Excel COM Add-In in `C#` using `Visual Studio 2013 Professional` which displays a `CustomTaskPane` as a right sidebar in Excel.

This is working perfect when running it directly from the IDE, but not working when installing it from the `setup` file generated when I published the solution.

The Add-In `MyAddIn` appears in the Add-Ins list, but it stays Inactive at all times when I try to activate it by pressing the `Go...` button at the bottom and then mark the add-in to activate it.

Any solution would help me a lot...
[image]

---

This problem is caused by the Settings configured in the project
[image]

This is how is use them:

```
public UserControlSDR()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string settingAdbKey = Properties.Settings.Default.adbeKey;
    string settingAdbUser = Properties.Settings.Default.adbeUser;
    string settingOpKey = Properties.Settings.Default.opKey;

    textBoxAdbKey.Text = settingAdbKey.Substring(settingAdbKey.LastIndexOf(":") + 2);
    textBoxAdbUser.Text = settingAdbUser.Substring(settingAdbUser.LastIndexOf("Text: ") + 6);
    textBoxOpKey.Text = settingOpKey.Substring(settingOpKey.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
}
```

If I remove the code below `InitializeComponent()` everything works fine ... why?

Comment: one small observation - all other addins have simple paths starting with c:\ only your addin has a file:// url so it could be that it is not trusted!

Comment: I'm sure that it should work even if it's not trusted

Comment: No. That is how VSTO works @Digvijay

Comment: @PatrickHofman - Thanks - i have not worked much with VSTO however with straight COM addins and thats why it looked odd. However Valip have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668777/how-to-troubleshoot-a-vsto-addin-that-does-not-load

Comment: Yes, it looks odd, but it works @Digvijay

Comment: I think the file path should end with `|vstolocal` too, but I might be wrong.

Comment: If it helps, I published the Add-In by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4BTLdIMYEY

Comment: @PatrickHofman I've found the problem, can you please check the updated question? Thank you!

Comment: In Visual Studio, use `Debug > Attach to Process...` right before you click that button. Then you can find out yourself.

Comment: Uninstall your app from Control Panel -> Programs -> Uninstall a program. Then open up Excel, choose "Blank workbook", go to File -> Options -> Add-ins -> COM Add-ins -> Choose "Go..." -> Select "MyAddIn" -> Choose Remove -> Click OK. Close Excel. Install your add-in. Open up Excel again. Now it should work.