# VSTO excel addin not working in excel 2013 after installing powerquery

Tags: c#, vsto, powerquery, clickonce, excel-addins

I am using VSTO in my project with WPF. This is working fine in Excel.
But when I install power query in excel2013,my VSTO AddIn is not working.
When I disable power query ,my AddIn will work fine.

Need solution for the above issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is not working in the add-in.

Comment: The add-in itself is not working. It is disabled by Power query.The load behavior becomes 2.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions at runtime in the add-in?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have got exceptions in the add-in's code at runtime. That is a possible reason for disabling the add-in. Try to enable logging for your add-in, see [Event logging for Office solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/event-logging-for-office-solutions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2022) for more information.

Also I'd suggest creating your own log file so, you could analyze it and find the cause at any point.

Comment: Following error added in event log:
Customization URI: file:[Path]
Exception: The deployment manifest could not be downloaded because a connection to the network could not be established. Ensure that you can connect to the network, and try again.
This is a stand alone application .
There is no log present in custom log.

Comment: Such error messages come from a VSTO deployed using ClickOnce installers. See [VSTO ClickOnce ends with "The application could not be downloaded because a connection to the network could not be established."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629215/vsto-clickonce-ends-with-the-application-could-not-be-downloaded-because-a-conn) for more information.